# Simulating a larger number of simultaneous users on iphone chat app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, chat

I'm making an iOS app like Kik messenger.

I'm worried that the chat will slow down once many users come on it.

How would you simulate this type of simultaneous condition at a super-early stage? I want to measure the delay time and see at what point things would slow down?

My backend is PHP/LampStack on a Linux RedHat server in the US. Many of my users will be out of the country and I'll be testing this out of country as well. (if this fact matter at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try out services such as [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/)?

Comment: I'll do that now too. There anything free for that? - thanks Bo :)

Comment: They still have free trial that you might want to check: https://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/free-trial.html  That may be able to help you :) .